# Add two parameters that result in another parameter of the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model that has the following parameters.

```
  create_table "colegios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float    "Kids"
    t.float    "Girls"
    t.float    "total_persons"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
```

I want to use the `new` method where I enter the number of`kids` and `girls` and I want to update the`total_persons` parameter that would be the sum of `kids` and`girls`.

Muy controller is:

```
  def new
    @colegio = Colegios.new
  end

  # GET /colegios/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /colegios
  # POST /colegios.json
  def create
    @colegio = Colegios.new(colegio_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @colegio.save
        format.html { redirect_to @colegio, notice: 'Successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @colegio }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @colegio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /colegios/1
  # PATCH/PUT /colegios/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @colegio.update(colegio_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @colegio, notice: 'Successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @colegio }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @colegio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_colegio
      @colegio = Colegio.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def colegio_params
      params.require(:colegio).permit(:niños, :niñas, :total_personas)
    end
```

Comment: Please use English to ask, and describe your question

Comment: Please review again.

Comment: I suppose the first line in `create` should be `Colegio.new` instead of `Colegios.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Colegio.rb model add this:

```
before_validation :sum_values 
.
.
...
private 

def sum_values 
  self.total_persons = self.kids + self.girls
end
```

The before_validation will run before saving the record.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `kinds` and `girls` column should be `integer` type not `float` type

Modify your strong parameter to explicitly set value `total_personas`

```
def colegio_params
  cp = params.require(:colegio).permit(:niños, :niñas)
  cp[: total_personas] = params[:colegio][: Kids].to_i + params[:colegio][: Girls].to_i
  cp
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, it is not a good idea to make a column(s) in DB the value of which can be easily derived from the same (or even different) table, because that is against the principle of database normalisation, namely, any duplication in data does more harm than good (except in some practical cases where the run-time overhead is too much).  In Rails, instead, define a new method.  In your case it is something like this:

```
def total_persons
  kids + girls
end
```

Then, use the method as, for example,

```
Colegio.first.total_persons  # => the sum of the two columns
```